# Floating QDockWidget minimum size

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget, qt5.4

I've designed a `QDockWidget` in Qt Creator. For some reasons it has a minimum size assigned (screenshot). I can change the size (e.g. to `0x0`) and save the form, but whenever I reopen the form it is reset to `60x38` . All child widgets have a minimum size of `0x0` .

Even if I change the size in code (runtime) as here

```
QSize min(10, 10);
this->ui->qw_NavigatorDockWidgetOuter->setMinimumSize(min);
this->ui->fr_NavigatorDockWidgetInner->setMinimumSize(min);
this->setMinimumSize(min); // QDockWidget
```

I cannot resize the **floating** (!) widget below a 60 width. Where is that constraint coming from and how can I reduce the width?

[image: QtCreator]

Answer (score 2):

Set both `Horizontal` and `Verical` `sizePolicy` to `Ignored` and you'll be able to modify the size down to the minimum you set.

Comment: Good hint, unfortunately does not change anything for me. I have set "Ignored" to all relevant widgets in the GUI design editor and in code. The size constraint remains.

Comment: Set it for the top level widget.

Comment: What do you mean by top level widget? I have the QDockWidget, its child widgets, or the main window. I have set "Ignored" to QDockWidget and all child widgets.